# How to solve error #value! in Excel, by using webservice formula that use Google Map API Distance Matrix in xml?

Tags: excel, xml, vba, excel-2013, google-distancematrix-api

Since our purchase of Google Map API Distance Matrix Advanced, we try to use a Webservice formula within Excel 2013, in XML, that would allow us to make several requests to retrieve driving mileage values between different origins to different destinations, and in addition, the related driving durations.

As an example, here is the formula used directly within an excel cell:

```
=SERVICEWEB("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=46.25361111,5.21666667&destinations=46.2125,5.32444444&mode=driving&key=my_key")
```

And then, as the cell is supposed to retrieve an XML format, I use another formula in another cell to check and retrieve the wanted value:

```
=SIERREUR(FILTRE.XML(G2;"/DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/distance/text");"0")
```

Nevertheless, when I enter the first formula, it appears to return a value error : #VALEUR!

But if I type the url in a IE or Chrome page, it works, I get the related response:

```xml
<DistanceMatrixResponse>
  <status>OK</status>
  <origin_address>
    47 Rue des Anciens Combattants, 01440 Viriat, France
  </origin_address>
  <destination_address>175 Rue Charles Robin, 01250 Jasseron, France
  </destination_address>
  <row>
    <element>
      <status>OK</status>
      <duration>
        <value>773</value>
        <text>13 minutes</text>
      </duration>
      <distance>
        <value>11478</value>
        <text>11,5 km</text>
      </distance>
    </element>
  </row>
</DistanceMatrixResponse>
```

So, looking at this, that should work properly in EXCEL and not be an error of #VALUE!...
And I don't either see any error in my formula.

So, I don't understand why Excel generates an error whereas everything seems correct.
Could you then help us to solve this issue, through a change in the formula or through some VBA code?

Comment: What is `SIERREUR` an what is in cell `G2`?

Comment: Can a single cell contain all the lines of the XML?